# Undo Write operation if offline

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, offline

I am attempting do the following

1. write a document to server.
2. wait for the success event and check for metadata to confirm if its written to server
3. if it is not written to server even after the time out (using a timer) undo the write operation.

this is for WEBRTC calls so if a user attempts a call but was offline and closes the app since it did not succeed. after a long time the receiver would receive a call and would be weird.

Answer (score 1):

There are no undo operations in Firestore.  The client SDK tries doesn't really give any way to discern if the app is online or offline - it simply tries its best to service the requests that you give it via the API.

If you want to perform some operation while only online, then use Cloud Functions to make an HTTP request to backend code that performs the actions you want.  If the app is offline, the HTTP request will obviously fail, and you can decide what you want to do from there.